# Go.mod fails to fetch private repo from AWS CodeCommit as part of Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, gitlab, aws-codecommit

I am trying to fetch a private repo as a library from AWS CodeCommit in my go.mod file as part of the build stage in my Gitlab pipeline.

I am using the the following in the Gitlab stage:

```
  before_script:
    - go env -w GOPRIVATE=source.org.gitlab,git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
    - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit --region us-east-1 credential-helper $@'
    - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
    - git config --global user.email "test@email.com"
    - git config --global user.name "username"
```

I have also set the AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_DEFAULT REGION as env variables in my Gitlab repo. For the access key and secret key, I am using an IAM User which has access to AWS CodeCommit.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: unable to connect to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:
git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[0: 52.94.204.165]: errno=Connection refused
```

I am not really sure what is going wrong here. Any hints/directions would be appreciated. Thank you.